# ModelChoiceField returns a number instead of its value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, modelchoicefield

I have a simple model for my csv files:

```
#models.py
class csvModel(models.Model):
    csvFileName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    csvFile = models.FileField(upload_to='tpData/csv/')
```

My script allows a user to upload a file

Then, I use a ModelChoiceField that allows a user to select one of the uploaded file:

```
#forms.py
class convertForm(forms.Form):
    fileToConvert = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=csvModel.objects.all(), label="Choose a CSV file to convert")
```

When calling  `is_valid()` I can access the value of the ModelChoiceField (e.g. if my csv file is named test1 I will get test1)

```
#forms.py
def clean_fileToConvert(self):
    print(self.cleaned_data.get("fileToConvert"))  #I get the name of the field (what I want)
```

But when I try to access this value just below the `is_valid()` , I obtain a number (e.g. 48 for a file, 49 for the following etc.)

```
#views.py
form2 = convertForm(request.POST)
    if form2.is_valid():
        print(request.POST.get("fileToConvert")) #I get 48
```

I even tried to `return self.cleaned_data.get("fileToConvert")` in the clean function but it does not work, I don't know how to access to the selected file name, url etc.

Comment: Use `form2.cleaned_data.get("fileToConvert")`, the POST data contains the raw pk and the form field converts it to an instance when cleaned/validated

Comment: Thanks @IainShelvington it worked, so should I always use cleaned_data when accessing the form values in the views after they get cleaned ?

Comment: Yes, form.cleaned_data is almost always what you want to use. It will contain the data that has been cleaned/parsed/converted into a useful value